# Is it possible to generate secp256k1 addresses?

Tags: cardano-address

[CIP-0049](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/governance/cardano-improvement-proposals/cip-0049/) introduces the secp256k1 elliptic curve to Cardano in order to provide the corresponding ECDSA/Schnorr signatures as primitives. What I don't understand about this is whether those primitives are restricted to be used in smart contract or if I can have a simple address generated from a secp256k1 public key.

*Note:* I'm new to the cardano ecosystem, so I apologize if I misused some concepts or terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SECP256k1 is currently just the verify functions for ECDSA/Schnorr signatures in a plutus script (smart contracts). Cardano uses ed25519 for its payment key pairs that addresses are derived.